# Connection lost to iscsi san after problem with san

Tags: vmware-esx, storage-area-network

We have a cluster running with 3 VSpere ESX4 server that all are connected to a lefthand san through iSCSI. This all worked well but a week ago there was a problem with the san. After fixing that problem the VMWARE server continued working but this weekend I saw that 1 server didn't have a connection with the SAN.
The other two work perfecly. I looked at all setting and I cannot find a problem. Nowhere I can't find any erros.

Has anybode a idea?

Thanks,

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tiny linux VM that alternately pings the hosts and the iSCSI box and logs its output to a file. Next time you have any storage problems look to the log to assist in fault detection.